# Get array of index from an NSIndexSet?

Tags: ios, nsindexset

To call `UICollectionView`'s `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths` I need array of indexPaths. But I have them in an `NSIndexSet`. Any elegant way to retrieve it, not by looping?

Comment: First answer in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237311/how-should-i-handle-the-nsindexset-from-kvo-to-update-a-table-view

Comment: `enumerateIndexesUsingBlock` is basically a loop though. But I do not think there is a way to do it without some kind of loop.

Comment: finally I resigned, and done with for-loop :)

Comment: more elegant than `for` or `for in` for sure

Comment: Well, i would not do it with a for loop, enumerating the indices is definitely prettier.